# R Plumber API simpleError in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact): subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, json, pdf, r-markdown, plumber

I am developing a plumber API which takes a JSON file as input and inside it is processed by an rmarkdown file to produce pdf output report.

I am getting following error:

simpleError in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact): subscript out of bounds

This is my plumber.R file code:

```
#* @apiTitle CustomerLytics
#* Echo back the input
#* parse JSON
#* @serializer  contentType list(type="json")
#* @param file:[file]
#* @post /pdf

function(
  
  file,  
  cmede,
  cklant,
  nmede,
  nklant,
  res
         ){
  

    
  
    res$setHeader("CustomerLytics","attachment; filename=result.pdf")

  tmp=tempfile()
    
  render("triaReport7.Rmd", tmp,
                    output_format="pdf_document",
                    
             params=list(file=file,
                     cmede=cmede,
                     cklant=cklant,
                     nmede=nmede,
                     nklant=nklant)
         )
  
  file_name=paste0(tmp,".pdf")
        
  readBin(outfile, "raw", n=file.info(tmp)$size)
  
}
```

In R console, I see rmakdown verbose:

Quitting from lines 126-400 (triaReport7.Rmd)

This is the code chunk in rmarkdown where this pointing to:

````
```{r}
df_S0_=file[[1]][[1]]
  
df_S1_=file[[1]][[2]]
```
````

This command chunk divides the file into two separate lists df_S0_ and df_S1_. Help me out. I tried many solutions but all in vain.

I have resolved this issue now. But there is another issue unfolded. When I want to get pdf through shiny app it works fine but when i do it through plumber api, I get following error now:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
<simpleError: LaTeX failed to compile C:\Users\ARUNSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwVTRAc\file2fb452774ca6.tex.
```

The line "restricted system commands enabled." does not appear when I do it through shiny and I get pdf output but this line appears when I do it via plumber API. I tried Yihui tips for debugging but none works.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `plumber` specifically. What is in `file`? Can you add a sample of that content (like the output of `dput(head(file))`?

Comment: @Kat Thanks Kat, I resolved this issue but there is another issue now. Pls suggest.